# JQuery ajax: Status 0 (FF, Chrome, Safari). Ok in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have two applications:

- AppA in localhost:1834
- AppB in localhost:3597

An html page of AppB call a method of AppA with the following code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:1834/Home/SomeAction',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
}).done(...).error(...);
```

AppA return an html fragment.

The code works fine with IE9 (also with type=POST, data=somejson, contenttype="application/json"), but it doesn't either with FF12 or with Chrome19 (Status=0, StatusText="error")

Is it related to cross-site scripting?

ps:

- The call to AppA works and AppA send a response with 200 status code.
- jquery 1.7.2.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a case of cross origin request. I am also having more or less similar problem, but not solved yet. Can you inspect the headers in FF and Chrome? Look at Origin header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is related to Same Origin Policy. Your request have to be on the same domain and the same port.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: In addition, Opera adds a "Security violation" error message. Thanks.